# Редирект с сохранением URL и GET параметров

Tags: .htaccess, get, redirect

Имеется код имеющий вид: `domain.com/api/type.method?param1=1&param2=2`
Я пытался редиректить его на `index.php` данным кодом:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Но если посмотреть переменную `route`, то там лежит только `type.method`, а `GET` параметры пропадают, я так понимаю из-за повторного знака `?`. Как можно сделать редирект в 2 переменные, в одну `type.method`, а в другую сами `GET` параметры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]*).([A-Za-z]*)?(.*) /api/index.php?type=$1&method=$2$3 [L,QSA]
```

Он переделывает запрос вида: `domain.com/api/type.method?param1=1&param2=2`

В запрос вида: `domain.com/api/index.php?type=type&method=method&param1=1&param2=2`

**P.S.** Скрипт собран из костылей и я не могу гарантировать его стабильную работу из-за небольших знаний в правилах `.htaccess`. Надеюсь, люди, понимающие в этом, напишут лучший ответ, но на данный момент оставлю этот вариант как промежуточный работающий ответ.